# How can I send a eth to other account from a contract

Tags: solidity

I have a contract code as shown below. I deployed it to Ganache network. The  `getContractBalance` returns `99.94 ETH` that means my account has 99.94 eth balance. When I try to transfer to 1 unit to other account by calling `transfer` method, it gives me below error:

```
transact to Inbox.transfer pending ... 
transact to Inbox.transfer errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

I don't understand why it shows `revert` error. What could be wrong with my code?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Inbox {
    string private message;
    address private owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns (string memory) {
        return message;
    }

    function getAccountBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(msg.sender).balance;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function transfer(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can transfer Ether");
        require(address(owner).balance >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        recipient.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: get contract balance returns the balance for `msg.sender` which is the account who calls it, right? How could it be contract's balance?

Comment: I think I should rename it to `getAccountBalance`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your contract actually has any ETH in it, so the transfer fails. To check ETH balance inside the contract use this:

```
address(this).balance
```

getContractBalance function would look like this:

```
function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
}
```

Comment: I tried to send eth to the contract by deploying it with some Wei, but the deployment fails with this error: `he called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.`

Answer (score 1):

As said by others:

```
function getAccountBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(msg.sender).balance;
    }
```

this will return the balance of the caller of the function.
If the function is:

- called by an **EOA** (Externally Owned Account) then the `msg.sender` *is the EOA*
- called by a **contract account** (opposite to an EOA) then the `msg.sender` *is the contract calling it*.

Your are returning your own balance which you stated to be `99.94` ETH,
however in your function

```
function transfer(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can transfer Ether");
        require(address(owner).balance >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        recipient.transfer(amount);
    }
```

- you are using `recipient.transfer()` which will transfer the amount **from the contract to the recipient**.
- Your smart contract probably has no ether.
- You implemented a `require` to check the **balance of the owner** but no `require` that the contract has **enough ether**.
- You are not checking that the `amount` is at least as big as the `msg.value` (the ether sent with the transaction)

Comment: I think I misunderstood that contact address and sender address. If I want to transaction ether from one account to another account, what should I change in the code?